# Calculus Velocity and Acceleration Problem.

Tags: calculus

Okay so this is the problem: "On a certain planet, a ball is thrown upward with a speed of 33 feet per second from the edge 
of a cliff 44 feet above the ground. When does it hit the ground? (use a(t) = −22).

I already know that the answer is 4 seconds but I don't understand how to get there. Can someone please guide me and explain to me the process of solving this problem? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:**  Start with the fact that acceleration is the derivative of velocity, which is the derivative of position.  We know that $a(t) = -22$, so integrate it to find the velocity, using the information about the initial velocity in order to find the constant of integration.  Then once you've found the velocity $v(t)$, you can integrate that to find the position, and again you'll have a new constant of integration that you can find the value of by using the information about the original position.  Once you've found the position $x(t)$, you can solve for the time $t$ where the position of the ball is at the ground, i.e. $x = 0$.

Comment: Okay, so I integrated the acceleration function to get v(t) to be -22t. How exactly do I go about finding the constant?

Comment: Would it v(t) be -22t + 33?

Comment: @Dylan Yes it would, because when you integrate you get $v(t) = -22t + C$, and then you use the fact that $v(0) = 33$ to solve for $C$, and you get $C=33$.

Comment: So I'm assuming s(t) = -11t^2 + 33t + 44?

Comment: Okay, so I used the position function I stated above, factored it out, and found 4 to be a zero as well as -1. Why is 4 the answer but not -1?

Comment: @Dylan Yes, your position function is right.  And the reason $t=-1$ doesn't make sense is that $t=0$ is when you threw the ball, so you can discard any times before you threw the ball.  So the only physically meaningful solution is $t=4$.

Comment: Awesome, I understand it now. Thank you so much!!